# How do I use nib with stylus from the command line?

Tags: command-line, stylus

I've got this stylus file:

```
@import 'nib'

div
  background linear-gradient(red, blue)
```

I've `npm install nib` and `@import`ed nib hoping to "[gain access to everything nib has to offer](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib#stylus-api)", but when I

```
> stylus file.styl
```

all I get is

```
failed to locate @import file nib.styl
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 9):

Try `use`ing nib with:

```
> stylus -u nib file.styl
```

From `stylus --help`:

```
Options:
   -u, --use <path>        Utilize the Stylus plugin at <path>
```